# OnResume Methods are not executing on launching new activity using startActivity(intent)

Tags: android

Suppose i have activity 'A' which is showing data fetched from online database say Number of questions attended.

User goes from Activity 'A' -> 'B' where he attended the questions and comes back to Activity 'A' after pressing 'back' button.

Inside Activity 'A' I have methods executing correctly, fetching data online and updating the TextViews, Which i am calling in from onResume() method..

Now problem is when i go back from Activity 'B' to Activity 'A', onResume is not executing and those methods are not executing..

When i click power button and put the screen on sleep and awake the screen, data is getting updated correctly.

I know the Lifecycle it says that onResume will execute.

I am simply using the below code for going back from 'B' -> 'A'

```
backProfileImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class));

            }
        });
```

and Activity 'A' is having onResume() method as

```
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);        
new GetContacts().execute();
updateAllViews();
pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

But  i dont know where i am doing wrong. Please advise

Comment: your ques is very unclear, please replace A, B with real activity name

Comment: I think you must add Activity A and B code or just told me the names im confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not call `finish()` use this

```
backProfileImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //call only onBackPressed
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not working, finish() will destroy the current activity i.e. 'B' but my data is not populating in 'A', which is not getting refreshed while coming back from B to A

Comment: @amulbhatia your A activity is ProfileActivity and your B activity is ... ??

Comment: Activity B is showing list of questions.. in recyclerview (Still not working after using onBackPressed)